# What is the flaw in my bitwise logic?

Tags: javascript, optimization, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

What I'm trying to do at the beginning of my function is easy to see from my comment

```
    this.move = function ( )
    {

        if (this.dx | this.dy != 0) return; // exit early if both this.dx and this.dy are zero
```

That is, I want the equivalent of `if (this.dx == 0 && this.dy == 0)`. I thought the bitwise `OR` is correct because `this.dx | this.dy` is not equal to `zero` if and only if `this.dx` has at least one bit on or `this.dy` has at least one bit on (or both have at least one bit on). But I must be wrong, because my test

```
    this.move = function ( )
    {
        console.log("this.dx = " + this.dx + ", this.dy = " + this.dy); // TEST

        if (this.dx | this.dy != 0) return; // exit early if both this.dx and this.dy are zero
```

is showing that the rest of the function is executing when `this.dx` and `this.dy` are both zero.

What's going on here?

Comment: You're using `!=` when you mean `==`. You want to return if they *are* both zero, so if `this.dx | this.dy` is equal to 0. There's also the precedence error that musically_ut has pointed out. Personally I would write `if (this.dx == 0 && this.dy == 0)` as it's clearer to read...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is the condition is executed as:

```
this.dx | (this.dy != 0)
```

Try this:

```
if (!(this.dx | this.dy)) return;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [precedence table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) The bitwise OR will be executed **after** the inequality check is done. For example:

```
[JS]> 0 | 0 == 0
1
```

Hence, your expression actually is executed as:

```
if (this.dx | (this.dy != 0)) { ... }
```

To fix the issue, parenthesize the bitwise OR: `if ((this.dx | this.dy) != 0)`.

---

Also, as @Jon-Skeet pointed out, the correct check probably should be with an `==`.

Comment: Should I do `!==` for an extra layer of protection?

Comment: @LarryPage You can use either in this case, but I personally prefer using `===` or `!==` whenever possible because I find them easier to reason about.